# 2 vector objects pointing to the same allocated memory

Tags: c++, vector, copy

In C++, how to make a copy of an existing vector pointing to the same allocated memory ?

e.g :

```
vector<int> o1;
o1.push_back(1);

vector<int> o2;
//Make o2 share same memory as o1
o2[0]=2;

cout << o1[0]; //display 2
```

EDIT : I haven't been clear about the objective : if o1 is allocated on the heap and gets destroyed, how can I create an object o2 that would point to the same allocated memory as o1 to keep it outside of the o1 scope ?

Comment: You cannot. There is no way to make the proposed solution work. There may be a solution to the currently undisclosed problem, but the requirements need to be made clear.

Comment: You could make `o2` a reference: `vector<int>& o2(o1);`

Comment: either use shared_ptr<vector<int> > or boost::shared_array< int > although with boost::shared_array you cannot resize your array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a `boost::shared_array` template.

This however shares a fixed-size array of data and you cannot modify the size.

If you want to share a resizeable vector then use

`boost::shared_ptr< vector< int > >`

What you can also do is `swap` the vector memory into a different vector.

```
{
   std::vector< int > o1; // on the stack
     // fill o1
   std::vector< int > * o2 = new std::vector< int >; // on the heap
   o2->swap( o1 );
    // save o2 somewhere or return it
} // o2 now owns the exact memory that o1 had as o1 loses scope
```

`C++11` will bring in "move" semantics allowing you to keep the actual memory in o1 with `std::move` thus

```
std::vector<int> && foo()
{
      std::vector<int> o1;
       // fill o1
      return std::move( o1 );
}


// from somewhere else
std::vector< int > o2( foo() );
```

Answer (score 3):

make `o2` a reference to `o1`

```
std::vector<int> &o2 = o1;
```

Comment: That doesn't yield "two vector objects".

Comment: agree, the question isn't 100% clear. I had to GUESS a pointer or a reference is what he means.

Comment: Yes, indeed it works for the simplified example I gave. But what if the first object o1 gets destroyed but I want to keep its allocated memory for o2 ?

Comment: This would require a dynamic allocation isn't it ? My problem is that o1 is allocated on the heap

Comment: if o1 is on heap, why can't?

Comment: To create o1 using a smart pointer I would have to use the operator "new" which would allocate o1 on the stack. I need o1 on the heap.

Comment: @YannAbrowitch "new" allocates on the heap by default. You woudl create a shared_ptr with `new` and then copy it. The dynamically allocated object will live as long as the two shared_ptrs are alive.